# displaying currency symbol before value using data attribute

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display currency before the value. I using data attribute to display value. Also need to use data attribute for displaying currency.

```js
$('#insert').click(function() {

  var theTotal = '12.00';
  var ProductSellingPrice = '23.00';
  var CartQty = document.getElementById("number").value;


  theTotal = parseFloat(theTotal + (CartQty * ProductSellingPrice)).toFixed(2);

  $('#total').attr('data-count', theTotal);
});
```

```css
p1[data-count]:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 8%;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size: 40%;
  padding: .2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .85);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="cart.php" class="p1" id="total" data-count="12.00" data-currency="&euro;">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" id="shakethis"></i>
</a>
<input type="number" id="number" value="" />
<button id="insert">Insert</button>
```

Above javascript is on clicking "insert" button the value get added of the product. Before that value need to display currency.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple `attr` values in a `content`:

```css
.p1::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 8%;
  content: attr(data-currency) attr(data-count);
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: .2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .85);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="cart.php" class="p1" id="total" data-count="12.00" data-currency="&euro;"><i  class="fa fa-shopping-cart" id="shakethis"></i></a>
```